# Changing order of arguments in predicate changes result

Tags: prolog

Hello I'm new to Prolog and some things about it just confuse me.

So I have this list of Facts and a predecate:

```
    parent(gerlinde,mark).
    parent(gerlinde,lena).
    .
    .
    (and so on)
    female(gerlinde).
    .
    .
    (and so on)
    male(mark).

    sister(S,X) :- parent(F,S),parent(F,X),male(F),
                   parent(M,S),parent(M,X),female(M),female(S),S\==X.
```

So if I do ?-sister(S,X). I get the answers correclty without the answer that S is the sister of herself (S=X). However, if I Change the order like that:

```
    sister(S,X) :- S\==X,parent(F,S),parent(F,X),male(F),
                   parent(M,S),parent(M,X),female(M),female(S).
```

or like that:

```
    sister(S,X) :- parent(F,S),S\==X,parent(F,X),male(F),
                   parent(M,S),parent(M,X),female(M),female(S).
```

then I suddenly get the answer S=X too. So why is that happening? In my understanding there should be no difference between both predicates.

Comment: You can attempt  to understand the behaviour using the debugger. Input `?- trace.` before your query, and observe what Prolog says about the program evaluation...

Comment: Ok, I've done that, but it still confuses me. Aksing ?-sister(S,eve) both at first do the same for a lot of steps until they both get to call:female(eve). In both versions this is followed by exit:female(eve) but the incorrect version then concludes exit:sister(eve,eve), whereas the correct one says redo:parent(x,eve) does some more steps and then concludes fail:sister(_131111,eve). In both versions I can't find a step indicating that Prolog checks the identity of S and eve at all

Comment: At the prolog prompt, you should play with different cases of `(\==)/2` with arguments that are instantiated or not. For example, if you did, `X = 1, X \== 2.` it would clearly fail. But what's the result of `X \== 2.` if you haven't unified `X` with a value? Does it succeed or fail? Then try it with, for example, `(\=)/2`: `X \= 2.` without unifying `X` before hand. Does that succeed or fail? You'll begin to understand the meaning of `\==` versus `\=`, and it explains why your results are different. @CapelliC was trying to get you to see that with the `trace`. :)

Comment: Ah, I've got it, thanks :)

Comment: So I've done a little more research on the difference between \== and \= (didn't even know \= existed too, thanks). So X \== Y means it can not be proven that X equals Y, thus this is always true when this is the first argument in my predicate, because it cannot be proven if one of these is not instantiated yet. And X \= Y means X cannot be unified to Y right? So if I used that one instead it would always be wrong, because we CAN unify that a female is the sister of herself, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `X\==S` is the same as `\+X == S`, and `\+T` means 'T cannot be proven'. So, in your second predicate:

```
 sister(S,X) :- S\==X,parent(F,S),parent(F,X),male(F),
                parent(M,S),parent(M,X),female(M),female(S).
```

When `S\==X` is called, both *S* and *X* are variables. Thus, it 'cannot be proven' that `S == X` and this goal succeeds.

Then, as the predicate continues to be evaluated, `parent(F,S)` will ground `S` - in your case, to `mark`.
Then, `parent(F,X)` will ground `X` - to `mark` again! And it is never required again that `S` be different from `X`. Of course, with `S  = X = mark` the predicate fails, as `mark` is not a female (`female(S)` fails). But not with `lena`; she will indeed be her own sister.